Can perf record associate build IDs with PIDs instead of paths to avoid overwriting when paths are identical?
When using perf record with the perf record -a option on a host machine to profile system-wide, I encounter an issue where executables in different containers have the same file paths. This results in build IDs overwriting each other since perf record identifies ELF binaries using these paths. Is it feasible to modify perf record to use process IDs (PIDs) as keys for storing build IDs to prevent this issue?  Or are there any alternative solutions to distinguish build IDs in such scenarios?
Thank you for your insights.
